# "un secteur du numérique": grammar?

Tags: adjectifs

I came across the phrase 'un secteur du numérique' and am not sure about the grammar.

> Smart city, IOT, IA, blockchain, emploi, time to action, media... Medinsoft, le cluster des entreprises du numérique qui rayonne dans les Bouches-du-Rhône, a poursuivi sa structuration, l'objectif étant de répondre aux besoins du terrain et parce que chaque secteur présente ses spécificités et que pour mieux l'adresser, autant l'adresser avec finesse. **Un secteur du numérique** qui sort, comme on le sait, grandit [*sic*] et renforcé de la crise.

Why is not simply 'un secteur numérique'?
Is the word 'numérique' here an adjective? If so, why is it preceded by an article?

Comment: https://region-sud.latribune.fr/economie/2021-12-01/les-pme-du-numerique-doivent-pouvoir-travailler-aussi-avec-les-collectivites-stephanie-ragu-medinsoft-897632.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is clear enough from a basic point of view. In "un secteur du numérique" the word "numérique" is a noun, a well defined singular noun which has been coined to name an industry. In "un secteur numérique", the word "numérique" is merely an adjective, and so the whole industry, as a concept, is not immediately made salient in the listener's mind. The adjective could in fact be used in relation to numbers in a general way, not specially binary numbers as they pertain to the processing of information, so this latter  term has not as much individuality, so to speak. I see that as one of the reasons, but perhaps more can be said.

---

*FranceTerme* :

[**numérique**](https://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/INFO964) n.m.
Journal officiel du 09/03/2021

Forme abrégée
Domaine
Informatique - Télécommunications

Définition
Ensemble des disciplines scientifiques et techniques, des activités économiques et des pratiques sociétales fondées sur le traitement de données numériques.

[**numérique**](https://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/INFO174)  adj.
Journal officiel du 22/09/2000

Forme abrégée

Domaine
Informatique

Définition
Se dit, par opposition à « analogique », de la représentation discrète de données ou de grandeurs physiques au moyen de caractères (des chiffres généralement) ; se dit aussi des systèmes, dispositifs ou procédés employant ce mode de représentation.

Note
En français, l'adjectif « digital » signifie « relatif aux doigts » et ne doit pas être utilisé dans le sens de « numérique ».

La directive concernant le mot « digital » est cependant assez mal suivie puisque ce mot est en fait utilisé de la façon contre-indiquée, en particulier dans les entreprises  (voir commentaire de [user Xoudo](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52574/un-secteur-du-num%c3%a9rique-grammar/52575?noredirect=1#comment110013_52575)) :  « *secteur digital, agence digitale, marketing digital* ».

---

Comment: s'il est important de noter que "digital" dans ce sens est un anglicisme, il faut dire qu'il est utilisé souvent comme équivalent à numérique (notamment en entreprise) : secteur digital, agence digitale, maketing digital.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, “*secteur*” refers to a part of the economy: a set of companies and other actors (government, schools, etc.) involved in a particular kind of goods or services. “*Numérique*” refers to everything around computers, from computer manufacturing to any business that's primarily about manipulating data with computers. “*Le secteur du numérique*” is roughly equivalent to “the tech sector”, but excludes advanced technology that isn't related to computers in some way. To include all advanced technologies, you can say something like “*les secteurs des hautes technologies*” or “*les secteurs à haute technologie*” (sectors of/involving high technologies). The construction is the same as “*le secteur de la chimie*” (“the chemical sector”), “*le secteur du luxe*” (“the luxury sector”), etc.

A potential weirdness in this sentence is the use of the indeterminate article *un*. The expression “*secteur du numérique*” uniquely qualifies what it's about, so normally it would need a definite article: “*le secteur du numérique*”. Here, the sentence uses an indefinite article and goes on to express a property of the thing. It's a way to emphasize the idea that the thing does not necessarily have that property: one could conceive a possible world where “*le secteur du numérique*” does not come out of the crisis at full strength and even reinforced. This construction can even be used with proper nouns. For example (randomish Google hit): “[rêver à nouveau d'une France industrielle](https://www.latribune.fr/opinions/tribunes/dix-ans-apres-rever-a-nouveau-d-une-france-industrielle-953759.html)”.